# Issue with Dynamic Remarketing Tag. The Product ID parameter is missing in 99% of the activity

Tags: google-tag-manager

When I go to Tag Google Ads details, I have this issue: "The “Product ID” parameter is missing in 99% of the activity of your Google Ads Tag".

Note, I implemented Dynamic Remarketing Tag via Google Tag Manager. In setting up Tag "Remarketing Google Ads" I inserted:

- ID Conversion: XXX-XXX-XXX;
- Custom Parameters: Use Data Layer {{google_tag_params}};
- Trigger: All pages.

Following you can see source code html for a product page that contains ecomm_prodid, ecomm_pagetype, ecomm_totalvalue:

```
<!-- BEGIN: Google TagManager Remaketing -->
<script>
var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
'event':'remarketingTriggered',
'google_tag_params': {
'ecomm_prodid': '721',
'ecomm_pname': 'MAGLIONE GIROCOLLO  IN LANA',
'ecomm_pcat': 'home',
'ecomm_pagetype': 'product',
'ecomm_totalvalue': '20.00'
}
});
</script>
<!-- END: Google TagManager Remaketing -->
```

So, I created in GTM a variable called google_tag_params with:

- Data Layer Variable Name: google_tag_params;
- Data Layer Version: Version 2.

As seen before, I used this variable in Remarketing Google Ads Tag, trying to capture at least: ecomm_prodid, ecomm_pagetype, ecomm_totalvalue needed to Display Remarketing.

When I use GTM in preview mode I have this:

- Send dynamic remarketing event data: false
- Variabile di livello dati:
- {ecomm_prodid: '721',
- ecomm_pname: 'MAGLIONE GIROCOLLO  IN LANA',
- ecomm_pcat: 'home',
- ecomm_pagetype: 'product',
- ecomm_totalvalue: '20.00'}
- ID conversione: 'XXX-XXX-XXX'
- Parametri personalizzati: 'DATA_LAYER'

Problem is issue "The “Product ID” parameter is missing in 99% of the activity of your Google Ads Tag" is still there.

I tried also check via Tag Assistant with Product Feed ID XXX-XXX-XXX, but I got this alert: Some products are not valid.

When I check on Metadata request in Tag Assistant I got this "event:gtag.config" and not parameters.

I searched for days on web, but did not find any solution.

Could you please assist me?

Thanks,
Francesco

Comment: The all pages trigger is wrong, look at the below reply and let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Create a dataLayer variable for each of your dynamic remarketing variable.

```
google_tag_params.ecomm_prodid
google_tag_params.ecomm_pname
google_tag_params.ecomm_pcat
google_tag_params.ecomm_pagetype
google_tag_params.ecomm_totalvalue
```

[image: DataLayer variables]

Use the following custom event as you have in the dataLayer `event` field.
[image: Custom Event]

Use the manually specify on your AdWords tag:

[image: Final tag]

Verify the implementation by checking in your browser network tab, filtering by the keyword `random`. You should see the dynamic remarketing request along with the key/value you've provided.